# multiple textures with single drawcall

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

hello i want to create multiple cubes with different textures for each cube.
to have the best performances i've created a single mesh with merged geometries. but i have a problem with the textures because until now i must have a draw call per texture.
i want to know if exist a method to have a single merged texture like the geometry, in this way i can create a one big texturized mesh with only one draw call.

my actual code is this.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var materials = [];

    for(var p: number = 0; p < 1000; p++){
        var height = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 50);

        var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 5, 10);        
        box.translate(
           Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 50), 
           Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 50), 
           Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 50));

        var texture = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(textures[p])});
        texture.needsUpdate = true;

        geometry.merge(box);
        materials.push(texture);                         
     }

      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);        
      el.setObject3D("mesh", mesh);
```

i think the way is to have a texture per geometry or to create different textures to merge in a single texture.
every advice is well accepted thanks in advance.

i use a-frame v.0.7.1 but in this case i think is more a threejs problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge all of your texture images into a single texture atlas. And then modify per geometry the UVs to point to the desired texture.

https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1

Snippet from that guide:

```
var texture = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('textureatlas.png')});

var bricks = [
  new THREE.Vector2(0, .666),
  new THREE.Vector2(.5, .666),
  new THREE.Vector2(.5, 1),
  new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)
];

geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [ bricks[0], bricks[1], bricks[3] ];
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = [ bricks[1], bricks[2], bricks[3] ];
```

Since you are merging the geometries, just need to make sure the UVs transfer over (perhaps they do automatically).

Comment: thanks. i think this is the solution. is possible to create a texture atlas with dynamic images? i have an array of images url from the web, but any image could be changed in any moment. then is helpful to create the atlas each time i load the page

Comment: You can draw them onto a canvas (see canvas drawImage API) and use that as a texture.